# @Import vs @ContextConfiguration for importing beans in unit tests

Tags: spring, unit-testing, spring-boot

I was able to set up and successfully run three different test configurations with SpringBoot 1.5.3

Method #1. Importing Bean with use of `@Import` annotation

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@Import({MyBean.class})
public class MyBeanTest() {
    @Autowired
    private MyBean myBean;
}
```

Method #2. Importing Bean with use of `@ContextConfiguration` annotation

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(classes = {MyBean.class})
public class MyBeanTest() {
    @Autowired
    private MyBean myBean;
}
```

Method #3 (with internal class configuration; based on [the official blog post](https://spring.io/blog/2011/06/21/spring-3-1-m2-testing-with-configuration-classes-and-profiles))

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(loader=AnnotationConfigContextLoader.class)
public class MyBeanTest() {

    @Configuration
    static class ContextConfiguration {
        @Bean
        public MyBean myBean() {
            return new MyBean();
        }
    }

    @Autowired
    private MyBean myBean;

}
```

Taking into account `@Import` annotation documentation

> Indicates one or more {@link Configuration @Configuration} classes to
>   import.

and the fact that `MyBean` is not a configuration class, but a bean class annotated with `@Component` annotation it looks like Method #1 is not correct.

From `@ContextConfiguration` documentation

> {@code @ContextConfiguration} defines class-level metadata that is
>   used to determine how to load and configure an {@link
>   org.springframework.context.ApplicationContext ApplicationContext}
>   for integration tests.

Sounds like it is better applicable to unit tests, but still, should load a kind of a configuration.

Methods #1 and #2 are shorter and simpler.
Method #3 looks like a correct way.

Am I right? Are there other criteria why I should use method #3, like performance or something else?

Comment: Does `MyBean` depend on any other beans? If not I would just instansiate it like `MyBean myBean = new MyBean();`

Comment: Yes, it depends on `org.springframework.core.env.Environment`.

Answer (score 3):

You actually don't need to specify the loader if you go with option #3. [From the doc](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/#testcontext-ctx-management-javaconfig)
In addition to the example from the doc you can override the env. with [@TestPropertySource](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/#__testpropertysource) if you need to inject properties in the environment without using the real ones.

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
// ApplicationContext will be loaded from the
// static nested Config class
@ContextConfiguration
@TestPropertySource(properties = { "timezone = GMT", "port: 4242" })
public class OrderServiceTest {

    @Configuration
    static class Config {

        // this bean will be injected into the OrderServiceTest class
        @Bean
        public OrderService orderService() {
            OrderService orderService = new OrderServiceImpl();
            // set properties, etc.
            return orderService;
        }
    }

    @Autowired
    private OrderService orderService;

    @Test
    public void testOrderService() {
        // test the orderService
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

It really depends if you're using one of the testing annotations Spring Boot offers or if you're building the context from scratch. The core support in Spring Framework requires you to provide a "root configuration" via `@ContextConfiguration`. If you're using Spring Boot, it has its [own way of detecting the root context to use](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/spring-boot-features.html#boot-features-testing-spring-boot-applications-detecting-config). By default, the first `@SpringBootConfiguration`-annotated type that it finds. In a typical app structure, that's your `@SpringBootApplication` at the root of your application's package.

With that in mind, using `@ContextConfiguration` with that setup is not a great idea as it would disable that lookup and will do just more than "importing beans".

Assuming that the context has been created for you and you want to add additional beans, there are two main ways:

If you need to selectively import components (on top of the default behaviour of detecting the right context to use), then `@Import` is absolutely fine. In the meantime, the Javadoc of `@Import` was polished to mention that importing components is absolutely fine and that it isn't specific to `@Configuration` classes:

> Indicates one or more component classes to import — typically @Configuration classes.

So, method #1 is definitely correct.

If the component is local to the test and you don't need to share it with another test, then an inner `@TestConfiguration` can be used. This is [also documented in the reference guide](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/spring-boot-features.html#boot-features-testing-spring-boot-applications-detecting-config).